# MySQL Query crashes my program even when in try statement

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

It errors out when the record couldn't be found `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
How can I keep it from crashing out and handle "undefined"?

```
let blacklisted = false;
    let conStr = "SELECT * FROM `blacklist` WHERE `id` = '"+message.author.id+"'"; 
    con.query(conStr, function(error, result, field) {
        console.log(result[0].id);
        if(result[0].id){
            console.log("Van")
            blacklisted = false;
        }
    });

if (message.author.id !== "397487086522990602" && blacklisted){/*Actual Code*/}
```

Comment: You could check if `result.length === 1`

Comment: result[0] (when you have the error) doesn't exist (is null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should add proper checks. Try catch is basically for connection/ query execution related failure not for if data not returned. 
So just add check if result[0] exists.

Hence folowing code should serve your purpose:

```
let blacklisted = false;
    let conStr = "SELECT * FROM `blacklist` WHERE `id` = '"+message.author.id+"'"; 
    con.query(conStr, function(error, result, field) {
        if(result[0] && result[0].id){ // add check for result[0]
            console.log("Van")
            blacklisted = false;
        }
    });

if (message.author.id !== "397487086522990602" && blacklisted){/*Actual Code*/}
```